# Caching issue in updating Mojarra from 2.0.3 to 2.0.4

Tags: caching, jsf-2, mojarra

I am now using Mojarra 2.0.3 and want to update to 2.0.4 in my JSF application.

Mojarra 2.0.3 resources are cached in thousands of my customer's machines and how can I force the browser to download new Mojarra 2.0.4 resources?

(I don't want to ask my customers, who are non technical users, to clear the cache because of the new software)

Answer (score 0):

Would the new version not have the version-name in the resource name? Are you talking about the browser caching JavaScript parts or JSF2?